# Flow input validation: Get Maximum field length

Tags: validation, visual-workflow, richtextarea

I'm trying to limit the input length of text field in a flow. The field is called "Name" and what I have so far is:

```
Len({!Name}) < 80
```

The point is: I want to have the maxLength of the field read dynamically, not statically at 80.

I tried things like `{!Name.getLength()}` or the `{!Length}` variable that is available under "Variable" resources (seems to always be 0).